# Yandex Maps API v3.0 - Обработка клика правой кнопкой мыши на маркер

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не могу понять из документации по Yandex Maps API v3.0, как обработать нажатие правой кнопкой мыши на маркер. Например, левое нажатие обрабатывается так:

```
    <YMapMarker
      coordinates={[37.114924, 55.782392]}
      draggable={true}
      onClick={myClickHandler}
    >
      <div>My marker</div>
    </YMapMarker>
```

А как обработать правое нажатие?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте **onContextMenu** вместо **onClick**

```
onContextMenu={myRightClickHandler}
```